# Speeding up data retrieval from SQL to Pandas for particular values of a column

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I am trying to train a attention model on a huge dataset (~150 GB). I have converted the CSV to a SQL database using odo. My current workflow is to select two thousand customers at random and pull their ten records from the database. Each customer has a maximum of ten records.But, pulling the data is taking a lot of time ( 2 minutes on average).
How can I speed up the data fetching process? My current code looks like this:

```
ids=# list of customer ids
df=pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM records WHERE cust_id IN(%s) LIMIT 20000' % ",".join(map(str,ids))',con=disk_engine)
```

EDIT:

I created the database using the following code :

```
from odo import odo, resource, discover
import sqlite3
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

dshape = discover(resource('original_csv.csv'))

odo('original_csv.csv', 'sqlite:///whole_data.db::records',dshape=dshape,header=True)
```

The CSV file contains cust_id and ~300 other features used for training

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your time issue is not with pandas but with your SQL engine.
If you didn't do it, you can add an index on `cust_id` field in your table `records`, this should speed up your query.

Comment: Could you add the statement of how your table `records` is defined? It would help to improve your query. (and yes your primary should be unique)

Comment: I have added details regarding the creation of the db. Is that what you asked for?

Comment: Moreover, the cust_id is not unique for each row. A customer with 10 records will occupy 10 rows in the database

Comment: Looking at your code, I don't think the library odo creates any index on your database. I don't know this library, but either they have an option to specify the index, either you have to create it by yourself afterwards. Also as the lines with cust_id are not unique, you can't have a primary key set on just this field, then an index only on this field should be added to speed up your query.

Comment: I added the cust_id as index and it worked like a charm! The retrieval is very quick now. Thank you.